# How to detect URL and redirect to 404 if it contains script tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, url

I have a webpage for example `www.testing.example.com/home`, now if someone manually add script tag onto the url bar like `www.testing.example.com/home/<Script>alert('asd')</script>` then it should not give alert, it should redirect to 404 page.

I want to say if my url has script tag then it should redirect to 404 page apart form giving the alert message.

How can this be achieved using Javascript?

Comment: have you tried executing it that way? like you said: *"www.testingjavascript.com/home/alert('asd')"*?

Comment: I don't see any script tag in that URL, and the proper way to protect yourself is by not putting URL parameter values inside scripts in the first place.

Comment: Can anyone tell me if url www.testingjavascript.com/home/alert('asd') will show an alert?

Comment: @agentmilindu i just wrote as an example . not conceptually.. in my question i mention about the script tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var regex = new RegExp("%3c.*%3e","i");
var script = regex.exec(window.location.href);
if (script) {
    window.location.href = "/404";
}
```